# malloc, memset and free correct usage

Tags: c, malloc, free, memset

I've a problem with the use of malloc, memset and free, which doesn't work as expected. The problems is with the latest function printf, instead of printing "test", it prints some weird characters and then test, something like "@#°test". Can you expalin me why? I've noticed that everything works fine if I do a memset after the second malloc. Also, I really don't get why everything works fine if I don't call the function "function()", even without a memset

Here's my code:

```
#define size 10
void function(){
   ...
   ...other code...
   ...
   char *b=malloc(size);
   read(file_ds,b,size); //file_ds stands for file descriptor, correctly opened with open function.
   memset(b,0,size);
   free(b);
}

void main(){
   ...
   ...other code...
   ...
   function(); //If I don't call this, everything works fine, even without a memset
   char *c=malloc(size);
   strcat(c,"test");
   printf("%s",c);
}
```

Comment: `malloc()` does not zero-initialize the allocated memory, nor does `read()` NUL-terminate your string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcat` expects that the address you give it points to a valid string, and it will attempt to find the end of that string by looking for a zero byte. Your pointer, however, points into uninitialized memory, and it is undefined behaviour to attempt to read it.

Changing `malloc` to `calloc` provides you with initialized memory. However, that may be overkill, since it's enough to have an initialized *initial segment*, which you can achieve like thisL

```
char *c = malloc(size);
c[0] = '\0';

strcat(c, "test");  // OK
```

Comment: So, if I want to put a string into a malloc and use it for specific string functions, I should ALWAYS do something like your examples, or a memset immediatly after the malloc?

Comment: @daimpa: Well, you should understand what the APIs you use expect and then meet the preconditions. I hate to suggest that it's possible to be a programmer by following a recipe or cook book. The only real answer is that you need to understand what you're doing. Typically this involves reading the manual, since nobody can remember the C API (which is insanely inconsistent). Certainly "always memset" would be terrible advice, notwithstanding that it would have made your code correct.

Comment: @daimpa: You don't need to initialize the memory if you  `strcpy (c, "test");`.

Comment: @kerrek SB I'm studying from a book but it doesn't seem good enough, but it's the one suggested and followed at university, only a little part of the exam has to do with c... I'm doing questions here to understand how things work :) Can you help me to understand also why if I do printf("%s",b) in the first function it prints exactly the same weird characters I see before "test" in main, and why strcat works correctly if I don't call function() in main?

Comment: @daimpa: Everything *isn't* fine. You cannot tell what is fine unless you can *prove* it from the documentation. Your program may be broken but not exhibit immediately visible bad behaviour (that has to wait until you've shipped it to millions of paying clients who'll sue you back into the stone age). I cannot do better than repeat my previous point: read the documentation and understand what you're doing (which includes understanding what every single function that you use is doing).

Comment: @daimpa: Just this once, an attempt to explain what you might be seeing: When `malloc` goes to the OS to get new, fresh memory, that memory is all-zero. So if you do nothing else, you may be witnessing such a zeroed memory area. If you already used and returned some memory, you'll end up with unpredictable content in later allocations.